# Validation of infinite input char \ number

Tags: c

I need to get a valid number from the user between 0-9 without duplicates.
The valid number can have any number of digit, from 1 to 10.
If the user type "space" or any kind of char, then the input is invalid.
My algorithm :

1) Create an array of char in size of 10, then initialize all cells to '0'.

2) For every char that reads from the user, check if the char actually between 0-9.

2.1) If true: count the respectively cell number +1.

2.2) Else "error".

2.3) If I get to a cell that already has +1, means this number already exist, then "error".

Now a few questions about my idea:

1) Is there any better\easy algorithm to do that?

2) The user doesn't type char by char, means I can get an infinite char length, so where do I store everything?

Comment: If you can't have two of any given digit, any input longer than 10 digits is an invalid number anyway.

Comment: @Dmitri that's right but still, I need to check char by char. Because the user can type: "14532" - which is less than 10 digits and also valid number. or can type: "2345s o$" which is less than 10 digits but not a valid number.

Comment: But you don't need to store the extra chars... if you get more than 10, the number is bad and you can just discard the extra chars.  If you get less than/equal to 10, then you can check that those 10 (or less) make a valid number.

Comment: @Dmitri That's right. So what is the best way to read char by char from the scanf?

Comment: Use `getchar()` in a loop instead of `scanf()`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to 2) is: you don't store the characters at all, you process them one by one. You only need storage to remember which digits you have already seen. I'd do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char seen[10] = { 0 };
    int c, loops;

    for (loops = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && loops < 10; ++loops)
    {
        if (!isdigit(c)) {
           printf ("Not a digit: %c\n", c);
           break;
        }
        c -= '0';
        if (seen[c]) {
           printf ("Already seen: %d\n", c);
           break;
        }
        seen[c] = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Try to modify this program as an exercise: reduce the storage requirements of the `seen[]` array. As written it uses one byte per digit. Make the program use only one bit per digit.

Comment: not sure yet what is EOF, but I'll look for it. BTW the ctype.h is only to use the function isdigit?

Comment: EOF is a macro expanding to the end-of-file value, a value distinct from any other char value. It is needed to, well, terminate the loop when EOF is hit. Remember: the user might only type 3 characters and nothing more, not even ENTER. On Unix, you can type EOF using Ctrl-D. Yes, ctype.h provides the prototype for isdigit().

Comment: Got it. Now I go over your code in debug, when I get to the loop I type my number, for example '2', it does the loop well but then in the 2nd iteration he enter into the 1st if and prints "Not a digit". Any idea why EOF doesn't work well?

Comment: Do you type 2 followed by ENTER? Then the ENTER is the character that's not a digit. If you don't want this, you need to add  `if (c == '\n') {break;}` as the first statement in the loop body.

Comment: I've got to hit the ENTER in order to type my number:), isn't?

Comment: No, you can also type 1234 followed by *two* Ctrl-D to signal end-of-file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88295/discussion-between-user3075653-and-jens).